# Why can't I use SetArgPointee() with googlemock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I am trying to set an "out" parameter on a mock with `SetArgPointee`.  Here's the code I'm testing:

```
DWORD bodysize = 1024;
char body[1024];
HRESULT hr = req->ReadEntityBody(body, bodysize, false, &bodysize, NULL);
```

`req` is an [IHttpRequest*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms694263%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and I want to set `bodysize`, argument 3, in the mock.  Here's the code from my unit test:

```
EXPECT_CALL(req, ReadEntityBody(NotNull(), Ge(1024), false, NotNull(), _))
    .WillOnce(SetArgPointee<3>(4))
    .WillOnce(Return(ERROR_HANDLE_EOF));
```

This results in the following strange error:

> error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'long' (gmock/gmock-actions.h:369)

If I comment out `.WillOnce(SetArgPointee<3>(4))`, the code compiles and executes correctly.  Here is the relevant definition in the mock itself:

```
MOCK_METHOD5(ReadEntityBody, HRESULT(VOID *pvBuffer, DWORD cbBuffer, BOOL fAsync, DWORD *pcbBytesReceived, BOOL *pfCompletionPending));
```

And, in case it helps, my [full mock of IHttpRequest](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6010824/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your actions are not being [combined properly](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#combining-actions).  As such, your `EXPECT_CALL` declaration is lacking a `Return`, which is why you are getting the error about trying to convert `void` to `long`.  Ensure that you are using a `DoAll()`:

```
EXPECT_CALL(req, ReadEntityBody(NotNull(), Ge(1024), false, NotNull(), _))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgPointee<3>(4), Return(ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)));
```

Comment: I obviously didn't understand actions before now, heh.  Thank you for the help!